# Why $µ_0$ and $ε_0$ are not considered to be $4π$ and $1/4π$?

Tags: units, physical-constants, si-units

I did some algebra...

In Planck unit, if make $\mu_0 = 4\pi$ and $\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi}$ you get:

$$\mu_0 = 4\pi \cdot \frac{m_p l_p}{t_p^2 I_p^2} = 1.2566368452237765 \cdot 10^{-6}  N \cdot A^{-2} $$

(where $4\pi$ is the supposed value of $\mu_0$, $m_p$ is Planck mass, $l_p$ is Planck length, $t_p$ is Planck time and $I_p$ is Planck current).

Which is very near to the CODATA value in SI and probably is the correct value.

CODATA: $1.25663706212(19) \cdot 10^{-6} N A^{-2}$

Similar for ε of vacuum:

$$\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi} \cdot \frac{t_p^4 I_p^2}{m l_p^3} =  8.85419142073371 \cdot 10^{-12} F/m$$

CODATA value: $8.854 187 8128(13) x 10^{-12} F m^{-1}$

It is clear to me that the measurement are approximations of this perfect mathematical values... $4\pi$ and $\frac{1}{4\pi}$,
so that $\mu_0\epsilon_0c^2=1$, and $c^2 = \frac{1}{\mu_0\epsilon_0}$ and $c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}}$, in facts:

$$\mu_0\cdot\epsilon_0 = 4\pi \cdot \frac{m_p l_p}{t_p^2 I_p^2} \cdot \frac{1}{4\pi} \cdot \frac{t_p^4 I_p^2}{m l_p^3} = \frac{t_p^2}{l_p^2} = \frac{1}{c^2}$$
in Planck units.

Couloumb constant $k_C$, at this point, is:

$$k_C = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} = \frac{c^2\mu_0}{4\pi} = c^2 \cdot 10^{-7} H m^{-1} = 8987548129.98536 N m^2 C^{-2}$$

So, we have correct and exact values for $\epsilon_0, \mu_0, c, k_C$ in Planck units, that is, respectively: $\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi}, \mu_0 = 4\pi, c=1, k_C=1$, and by multiplying for their dimensions expressed in Planck Units we obtain the correct, exact, values in SI.

Comment: The numbers in parentheses at the end of the cited values are the digits in which there is uncertainty. As you can see, their values do not agree with 4pi or 1/4pi even in digits that we have measured precisely. In short, they are not approximations.

Comment: First, you should format using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Second, I am not sure what is going on here. What calculus did you do? What are $m$, $l$, $t$, and $I$? These values are chosen so that $c=1$. They aren't measured. In fact we actually define what $c$ is and we adjust our units accordingly.

Comment: How do you adjust l and t given c?

Comment: Did you mean “I did some *algebra*”?

Comment: Is there some reason that you are putting the subscript 0 on the $\epsilon$ but not on the $\mu$?

Comment: @G.Smith usually i don't find the subscript on $\mu$....

Comment: Yep @G.Smith i did some algebra.. the point stills. Which is the real bound between $\mu$ and $\epsilon_0$ and why them seems to imply $4\pi$

Comment: That’s interesting. I have never seen it without the subscript. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability

Comment: You have discovered a nice property of Planck units. It is simply because Planck units set $1/4\pi\epsilon_0$ to 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units

Comment: @G.Smith, I didn't see it, ops :p
But, if so, why the values are still measured and different from $4\pi$ times the units?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94824/discussion-between-m-manfredi-and-g-smith).

Answer (score 3):

They do indeed have these values in Planck units. This is because in Planck units $1/4\pi\epsilon_0$ and $c$ are set to $1$, and

$$c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}}.$$

Planck units are not in everyday usage because your height would be about $10^{35}$ and most people don’t even know what that means.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the meter has recently been redefined in Planck lengths...
I'd have rather prefer to use a multiple of Planck length, giving it a new name, and different from the meter (like foot or knots are).
So, for instance, 6.18714249917247e+34 is a meter in Planck length,
you can take e33 lp to define "the new centimeter", and 100 times that gives the "new meter".... so that 1.616255 is the ratio between the old meter and the new meter, and is a limited and precise number, still a multiple of lp.

Comment: You’re wrong. The meter was not redefined in terms of the Planck length. The Planck length is not known to high accuracy because $G$ has not been measured to high accuracy. So Planck lengths are completely unsuitable as measurement units.

Comment: According to Wikipedia the Planck length is known to only 5 or 6 significant digits. To metrologists, this is pathetic.

Comment: Yep, sorry. It is the Kg that has been redefined on the base of h :-)

Comment: Following this definition, the 2 constants have the values of 4π and 1/4π.
Why the CODATA values differ?

Comment: They have those nice values *in Planck units*. They have the ugly CODATA values *in SI units*. The *definition* of Planck units makes those nice values nice. The *definition* of SI units makes those ugly values ugly. You could have units where both constants are 1, which might be even nicer.